# Slack slash command modal windows instantly returns an error

Tags: python, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-block-kit, slack-bolt

After submitting the modal, Slack **instantly** responds with `{"ok":false,"error":"dispatch_failed"}`.
My backend doesn't even receive the requests from Slack.
The app was working a few hours ago.

Is the problem on Slack's side?

```
from slack_bolt import App
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


app = App(
    token='token',
    signing_secret='signsecret'
)


@app.middleware
def log_request(logger, body, next):
    logger.debug(body)
    next()


@app.command("/test")
def handle_command(body, ack, client, logger):
    logger.info(body)
    ack()

    res = client.views_open(
        trigger_id=body["trigger_id"],
        view={
            "type": "modal",
            "callback_id": "test",
            "title": {"type": "plain_text", "text": "Gratitude Box"},
            "submit": {"type": "plain_text", "text": "Submit"},
            "close": {"type": "plain_text", "text": "Cancel"},
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "input",
                    "block_id": "my_block",
                    "element": {"type": "plain_text_input", "action_id": "my_action"},
                    "label": {"type": "plain_text", "text": "Say something nice!"},
                }
            ],
        },
    )
    logger.info(res)
    print('command end')


@app.view("test")
def view_submission(ack, body, client, logger):
    ack()
    logger.info(body["view"]["state"]["values"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.start(3000)
```

I checked the permissions of the Slack app and tried various solutions, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just calling `client.views_open` instead of saving it to a variable.

Comment: Please elaborate the details of applying your proposal, how it works and why it helps.

Comment: sorry, i can only come up with "it worked when i did" but i realize i was way off base! i have a new idea, i think in `handle_command` he's calling `logger.info(body)` too early - in the first line of code before he's even done anything to warrant a body. this might slow down the api to the point it can't execute in time.

Comment: You are aware that you can [edit], aren't you?

Comment: i chose to respond to you because you commented on my response. my bad...

Comment: That is Ok. I pointed out a way how you can incorporate your new idea in the most helpful way. I hope that did not hurt you, otherwise please accept my apology. The possibility to edit is also what you can use to undo my edit, in case you do not like it. I think that it got your post closer to [answer] and thereb yimproved your chance for positive reception, but it still is your post.